# Restart one app from sub-apps NODE

Tags: node.js, express

I have two apps 
**/app1**
**/app2**

I am running both on same port
using

```
   app
  .use('/app1', require('./app1/app').app)
  .use('/app2', require('./app2/app').app)
  .listen(80);
```

How can I restart only one app.
Without affecting other.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You are not running two apps on one port, you are running one app (one Node.js process) that handles several API paths. So if, by *restart*, you mean stop the process and then start the process, then it is impossible.